# Vue.js on dynamically created document element is empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to do the following in a [playground](https://squint-cljs.github.io/squint/?src=KHJlcXVpcmUgJ1siaHR0cHM6Ly9lc20uc2gvdnVlQGxhdGVzdCIgOmFzIHZ1ZV0pCgooZGVmb25jZSBlbHQKICAoZG90byAoanMvZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCAiZGl2IikKICAgIChqcy9kb2N1bWVudC5ib2R5LnByZXBlbmQpCiAgICAoc2V0ISAtaW5uZXJIVE1MICI8ZGl2IGlkPVwiYXBwXCI%2BCiAgPGJ1dHRvbiBAY2xpY2s9XCJjb3VudCsrXCI%2BCiAgICBDb3VudCBpczoge3sgY291bnQgfX0KICA8L2J1dHRvbj4KPC9kaXY%2BIikpKQoKKC0%2BCiAgKHZ1ZS9jcmVhdGVBcHAKICAgIHs6c2V0dXAgKGZuIFtdCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgezpjb3VudCAodnVlL3JlZiAwKX0pfSkKICAoLm1vdW50ICIjYXBwIikp&repl=true):

```js
var vue = await import("https://esm.sh/vue@latest")
elt = document.createElement("div")
document.body.prepend(elt)
elt.innerHTML = `<div id="app">
  <button @click="count++">
    Count is: {{ count }}
  </button>
</div>`
app = vue.createApp({setup() { return {count: vue.ref(0)}}});
app.mount("#app")
```

This basically erases the content from the div but doesn't do anything else. What am I doing wrong?

Update: it turned out the import I was using from esm.sh didn't work, but this one does does:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.10/dist/vue.esm-browser.js

Comment: The syntax used is fine.  It works in a typical JS sandbox such as [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bodgcqyj/).  I'm not familiar enough with the squint playground or ClojureScript language to understand why it's not working there.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo whatever is passed into `createApp` becomes the root component. Whatever inner HTML exists inside the mount container [becomes the root component template](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#in-dom-root-component-template) if not given a template option.

Comment: Note that this doesn't really have to do anything with squint. I tried out the above in plain JavaScript, in a console. vue is the result of `var vue = await import(""https://esm.sh/vue@latest")`, I'll add that

Comment: Found a repro. This works:

https://jsfiddle.net/dvn5jrtw/

but this one doesn't:

https://jsfiddle.net/donxrbuz/

Seems an issue with the esm.sh version of vue probably.

Comment: Updated question with working solution

Answer (score 0):

The import I was using from esm.sh somehow didn't work.
This one did: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.10/dist/vue.esm-browser.js